# Managing a rankings list with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

For a sports club I am in, I want to manage a rankings list with MySQL on the website.

We have a tournament system where players can participate (or not) once a week and get points. Those points are somehow processed and a rankings list should be created on the website.

I am not so experienced with MySQL so I want to know if the system I thought of is good or another approach would be better.

I thought of having two tables:

```
players
-------
ID (unique primary key)
Name
Surname
+other arbitrary stuff

tournaments
-----------
ID (unique primary key)
Date
player (secondary key,  points to player ID)
+ columns for results of that player in this particular tournament
```

on the website I would then query the tournaments table, sort for ID and Player and process the results to compute a rankings list.

Is this a good approach or is there a better, more convenient way to do this?

Comment: No. The "+ columns" bit is wrong. See normalization. However, the "process the results" bit could be fine. Not enough info to say more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may find later that it would be more convenient to have one more table.

I would change your tournament table to something more like:

```
tournaments
-----------
ID (unique primary key)
Date
~Location
~+Other stuff about the tournament as a whole
```

And then add a table:

```
results
-----------
player_id (points to player ID)
tournament_id (points to tournament ID)
+results
```

The reasoning is because it will make it easier to filter on a single tournament, and many players could share the same tournament info without duplicating the results on each player.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I did a similar thing with a poker league I was in. This extra table will also allow you to generate statistical information per player without having to touch the data on the tournament table. Such as how many tournaments played by this player, their win/loss ratio etc.